# Count value in column by hours and add header

Tags: awk

In column 3 the value is hour, I will like to print the header from 0 to 23 hrs and count in column 3 the times repeated by hr. If not value for hr is found then print 0.

**Input file**

```
123 3 3
122 3 3
122 4 4
122 3 4
122 4 4
122 5 5
122 3 12
122 4 15
122 5 20
122 5 20
```

**Output desired**

First row = Header 0 to 23 hrs separated by,

Second row = Values found for each hr., If not value is found print 0.

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23
0,0,0,2,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0
```

**To count by hr, I tried**

```
awk '{a[$3]++} END {for(i in a) print i, a[i]}'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

another `awk`

```
$ awk '{a[$3]++} 
    END{while(i<24) 
          {h1=h1 s i+0; 
           h2=h2 s a[i++]+0; 
           s=","} 
        print h1 ORS h2}' file

0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23
0,0,0,2,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0
```

ps. looks like a variation of @JamesBrown's answer.

Comment: Sweet that `s=","` in loop. Why I never thought of that. Also, not a variation, an improvement. ++

Comment: yes, lazy separator initialization; handles first element case simpler than checking.

Comment: aside from the implementation details, setting up both lines in one loop is the main idea.

Comment: Karakfa, is there the possibility to keep always 2 dig in header. E.g. 00 istead of 0, and 01 instead of 1 ect.

Comment: change `h1=h1 s i+0` to `h1=h1 s sprintf(%02d",i)` for zero padded numbers.

Comment: Tks a lot Karakfa

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk '
{ a[$3]++ }                              # hash them
END {
    for(i=0;i<=23;i++) {                 # loop the hours
        b=b (b==""?"":",") i             # collect hours to b
        c=c (c==""?"":",") (a[i]?a[i]:0) # and counts to c
    }
    print b ORS c                        # output them
}' file
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23
0,0,0,2,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS=","
  for(i=0;i<=23;i++){
     printf("%d%s",i,i==23?ORS:OFS)
  }
}
{
  a[$3]++
}
END{
  for(j=0;j<=23;j++){
     printf("%d%s",a[j],j==23?ORS:OFS)
  }
}'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23
0,0,0,2,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the for-loop slightly:

```
for(i in a) print i, a[i]
```

To:

```
for(i=0; i<=23; i++) print i, a[i]+0
```

Transpose the output with `rs`:

```
awk ... | rs -c' ' -T
```

Output:

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23
0   0   0   2   3   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0
```

If you are certain about the csv output, use `tr` at the end:

```
awk '{a[$3]++} END {for(i=0;i<=23;i++) print i, a[i]+0}' | rs -c' ' -T | tr -s ' ' ,
```

Output:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23
0,0,0,2,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0
```

Comment: Gotta <3 `rs` .

Comment: Btw. `datamash` can also do it, e.g. in this case: `datamash -t ' ' transpose`